# Custom ControlValueAccessor in template-driven forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a custom `<data-input-text>` component which has two modes: regular and disabled. Here is the **template** (I've simplified it a bit for demo case):

```
<label  *ngIf="!disabled"
    class="field-label" 
    [ngClass]="{'focused' : isFocused, 'with-errors' : errors}">
    <input class="field-value" 
            [type]="type"
            [required]="required"
            (focus)="onFocus()"
            (blur)="onBlur()"
            [(ngModel)]="value"
            #fieldInput="ngModel">

</label>
<div class="field-label" *ngIf="disabled">
    <span class="field-value">{{ value }}</span>
    <span class="field-name">{{ label }}</span>
</div>
```

In the **parent form**, I use this component in the following way:

```
<form #profileForm="ngForm">
    <data-text-input
          label="lastName"
          [required]="true"
          [disabled]="userIsRegistered"                    
          name="lastName"
          ngModel></data-text-input>
</form>
```

`userIsRegistered` returns a boolean, which should switch between the input field or spans within the component. It all works fine until here.

I set the **form in the parent component** to match the BehaviorSubject like this:

```
 this._sub = this.dl.selectedEmployee.subscribe( u => {
  if ( u.id ) {
    this.isLoading = false;
      setTimeout( () => {
        this.profileForm.setValue(u);
        this.profileForm.control.markAsPristine();
      }, 10);
  }
});
```

Here is the custom ControlValueAccessor **component**:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, forwardRef, 
      AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnChanges, 
      NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, 
      ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, 
      Validator, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
   selector: 'data-text-input',
   template: `
   <label  *ngIf="!disabled"
       class="field-label">
       <input class="field-value" 
               [type]="type"
               [required]="required"
               (blur)="onBlur()"
               [(ngModel)]="value"
               #fieldValue="ngModel">
       <span class="field-name">{{ label }}</span>

   </label>
   <div class="field-label" *ngIf="disabled">
       <span class="field-value">{{ value }}</span>
       <span class="field-name">{{ label }}</span>
   </div>
     `,
     providers: [
       {
         provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
         useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> DataTextInputComponent ),
         multi: true
       },
       {
         provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
         useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> DataTextInputComponent ),
         multi: true
       }
     ]
   })

   export class DataTextInputComponent implements OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor, Validator  {

@Input() public disabled: boolean = false;
@Input() public label: string;
@Input() public required: boolean = false;
@Input() public type: string = 'text';
@ViewChild('fieldValue') public fieldValue: FormControl;

// infrastructure
public registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.propagateChange = fn; }
public registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.propagateTouch = fn; }

private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
private propagateTouch = (_: any) => { };

/**
 * inner value
 */
private innerValue: any = null;

/**
 * on changes hook
 */
public ngOnChanges(): void {
    if ( this.disabled ) {
        this.propagateChange(this.innerValue);
    }
}

/**
 * input events
 */
public onBlur(): void {
    this.propagateChange(this.innerValue);
    this.propagateTouch(true);
}

/**
 * value accessor setter and getter
 */
public get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
};

public set value(value: any) {
    if ( value !== 'undefined' ) {
        this.innerValue = value;
        this.propagateChange(value);
        this.propagateTouch(true);
    }
}

/**
 * value accessor implementation
 * @param value 
 */
public writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
        this.innerValue = value;
    }
}

/**
 * validation
 * @param c 
 */
public validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.errors = (this.disabled) ? null : this.customValidate(c);
}
private customValidate(c: FormControl): {} {
  if ( c.touched ) {
    // some validation logic which is not relevant here;
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
}
```

There are other components used in the form, too (like a color picker and a ng-select).

So the weird part is this. The form value is set alright. No errors. The values are displayed correctly (for both, `disabled` and `!disabled`) within data-text-input components, as well as other components in the form). The weird part is that when I inspect the `this.profileForm` object with the debugger, the `controls` property has all of the controls with their respective values, but the `value` property of the form misses those, where `disabled` property (aka no input field) is set to true.

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/nbWQZzQjhGae622CanGa?p=preview

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see email control in your code. Can you create a plunker demonstrating your issue?

Comment: I've updated the question with the plunker

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Also, you are required to post all code that shows the problem here, not a plunker which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob, have you downvoted the question because of the rules? If yes, please vote it up again, because I've corrected both points. I do not want the discussion to go in the wrong direction here.

Comment: You need to add whatever in your plunker that is relevant to solving this. Then you can remove the plunker link altogether. I did not downvote

Comment: All the relevant information is in the question already. The Plunker is there only for convenience. I will leave the link in place for now. If you can help with the answer, I will deeply appreciate it. Otherwise, please refrain from turning this into the discussion on procedures and rules. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to help not get your question closed for the reasons given. If you do not wish such help, I will oblige.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was not obvious, until I have traced down the way of setting of a value down to `AbstractControl.prototype.updateValueAndValidity` and it turned out, that using the variable name `disabled` was a bad idea here:

```
<form #profileForm="ngForm">
    <data-text-input
          label="lastName"
          [required]="true"
          [disabled]="userIsRegistered"                    
          name="lastName"
          ngModel></data-text-input>
</form>
```

I have renamed the `disabled` property to `isReadOnly` – 'cause `readonly` is also an attribute which might be checked elsewhere and also a TypeScript interface – and, tada, it works.